# Use NumberFormatter with C format (e.g. "%6.3f")

Tags: ios, swift, nsnumberformatter

Are there any extra functions to use the `NumberFormatter` (Swift 5) with a String that describes a C format?

Example: 12.3456 (Float) with "%6.3f" (C format as String) should turn into 12.345 (also Float)

Unfortunately Apple's [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/numberformatter) doesn't provide any examples.

I'm aware of `maximumIntegerDigits` and `maximumFractionDigits` and I know that you can use "%6.3" with `NSLog` and `String(format: .......)` but is there a function for `NumberFormatter` that turns the number directly into a Float or Double (not into a String), using the specified C format?

Comment: The answer to your question is no.

Comment: Why do you need something to convert a format specifier into a number formatter? Why can't you just use the methods of NumberFormatter to get the result you want?

Comment: That's a pity, I'm going to split up the String myself then. Thanks for your quick reply!

Comment: 1) A NumberFormatter does not accept printf-style formats. – 2) A NumberFormatter converts a number to a string, or vice versa, but not number to number. – 3) Neither `12.3456` nor `12.345` can be represented exactly as floating point numbers, so that your task will (almost) always result in rounding errors.

Comment: @rmaddy My app has a table with a TextField in each cell. Users can enter a number in the TextField and I then format that number according to the C format String. I'm downloading this format information from a server and it can be different for each cell, so I can't just predefine 'maximumFractionDigits'.

Comment: If you are downloading format information from a server, why not use a better way to define the format? Maybe some JSON with different fields for the different parts of the format.

Comment: @MartinR 2) Oh, I didn't know you can't use the formatter for number -> number. Is there anything built in that can and that also accepts a "formatting info"? 3) I'm aware, Double has the same problem.

Comment: @rmaddy Yes, it's indeed a JSON file I'm reading on the server ;) but I've got no control over the actual data inside and have to work with the String it's giving me.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to use `printf`-style format strings, I would not suggest using `NumberFormatter`. It’s not designed for that. Just use [`String(format:_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string/3126742-init). You appear to be reluctant to do that, but it’s not clear why.

So I might suggest:

```
func convert(format: String, _ value: Float) -> Float? {
    let string = String(format: format, value)
    return Float(string)
}
```

You said:

> Example: 12.3456 (Float) with "%6.3f" (C format as String) should turn into 12.345 (also Float)

Just to be clear, the following will produce `12.346`, not `12.345`. The `printf`-style format strings round, not truncate.

```
let value: Float = 12.3456
print(convert(format: "%6.3f", value) ?? "Unable to convert")
```

---

By the way, if you want accurate representation of the value represented by the `printf`-style format, rather than generating a floating point type, you could generate a `Decimal`:

```
func convert(format: String, _ value: Double) -> Decimal? {
    let string = String(format: format, value)
    return Decimal(string: string)
}
```

It just depends upon what you’re doing with this final result. I’ve also changed this to use `Double`, as it is very easy to exceed the meager 7 decimal digit precision permitted by `Float`.

Comment: `Just to be clear, the following will produce 12.346` - sorry I have to cut you off right away: Whatever version I use, it must not round the result, only truncate! In my app a user can enter a number, which I save in a JSON file and I then also display a truncated version of that number (according to the format) in my app. Why I asked for a solution that doesn't produce a String: Because I know how to do it with a String (e.g. split with ".", then just cut off the Strings) but I was wondering if it there's a built in solution that formats the numbers directly - without parsing afterwards.

Comment: I tested using `String(format:....)` too and it looks like you have to be careful with that: With a single-digit Integer a space is added at the beginning of the String and parsing to Double then produces `nil` (force-unwrapping will crash the app). So don't forget to trim the result before you parse it: E.g. `String(format: "%5.2", 1).trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces)`.